# HTML error checker

Tags: asp.net, html, parsing, message

I'm using Asp.net., Assuming I'm allowing user to post messages in my site with HTML tags. How do I ensure he has properly closed all the tags? Is there any HTML-tag-checker available that tries to parse tags and report errors if any?  May be just like the BLOGGER has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily parse the text yourself. Define a list of tags that are allowed that require closing (strong, em, etc.). Parse the code and take each HTML tag as a token and push it on to a stack. When a closing tag is found, peek at the top item and if it is not the complement to the found closing tag, the HTML is improperly nested.

Assuming paired tags/closing tags are removed from the stack, the residual elements are the tags which are started but not completed. This is only a rudimentary approach, but it may only be a few lines of code to identify improperly nested tags or unclosed tags.

Comment: Looks like a way. Let me try. Thanks!

Comment: Quicker to define the list of tags which DON'T require closing.

Comment: Ambrose: Correct; I was assuming OP was only intending to allow a limited amount of HTML.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [HTMLTidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) to make sure the HTML is well formed. Not sure if it will report errors without fixing them but it's open source so you could hack it to do that.

Comment: Not sure about ASP.NET support but it's integrated well with PHP and it is superb there.

Comment: You will still need to parse the results of Tidy to make sure only whitelisted elements/attributes are present. But at least you can use Tidy to make it well-formed XHTML, so you can use a simple XML parser for the task.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could try one of the WYSIWIG editors ... (good ones include http://www.fckeditor.net/, http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/, http://freetextbox.com/) you should be able to force it into "source mode", and they will probably tidy up bad HTML for you (although I haven't actually tied this technique myself :D)

Comment: May be this is what I wanted? Thanks for saving me from reinventing wheels. I'm crazy.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the online html validator by the wc3 at http://validator.w3.org/
,But remember to make sure your whole doc is valid outside of the comments first otherwise it could be quite an interesting trip.

Comment: This looks nice, but I'm just thinking how will I send a particular text content here, this is expecting an URL. May be I should dynamically render my conentent into a HTML page and send it to this validator?

Answer (score 0):

Just an off topic idea - use a Wiki-style engine. That way you can format the HTML yourself the way you want it.

Answer (score 0):

The webdeveloper toolbar addon for firefox has a function that allows you to validate the html of the page you are currently looking at using the w3c validator - tools->Validate Local HTML.

It's probably using functionality available in the validator anyway.  I think it may create a temporary html file and upload it.